# Kinda "method overloading" in Go?

Tags: go, overloading

Assuming I got a type named `State`:

```
type State struct {
    // ... does not matter what is inside
}
```

along with a method defined on it:

```
func (s *State) prettyName() string {
    return "I am a state!"
}
```

Currently there is no way I can alter `prettyName()`'s behavior. I known that `Go` intentionally escapes OOP-like inheritance and methods overloading and this would probably never change, but still: what if I need `prettyName()` to behave differently depending upon whatever factor? The only solution I see is:

```
type State struct {
    _prettyName func() string
}
func (s *State) prettyName() string {
    return s._prettyName()
}
```

Is there a better `Go`-style way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Have you considered interfaces?

Comment: @mkopriva, you mean, having a number of `StateABehavior`, `StateBBehavior`, ... - all impelmenting the same `IState` interface, which in case of `Go` - just exposing the same number of methods of the same signature and name?

Comment: Correct, although if you want to do this "overloading" for only one method you can embed the interface into State and then set the implementation according to the "whatever factor".

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/64QjEICmI4q

Comment: @mkopriva, wouldn't it require a named instace per each behavior? AFAIS, the way I did it allowes to build an object on the fly - no named instances are required and yet I can keep other code bound to the `IState` interface.

Comment: Yes it would require named types since you cannot put methods on unnamed types, if avoiding the declaration of new types is part of the requirement maybe add that to the question. In that case you can stick to your solution with the function field, they are pretty common and present even in the std lib.

Comment: ... basically to change the behavior of the State type based on the "whatever factor" you have two options, using function fields or interfaces. Well, there's a third option, which is using conditional statements inside the method you would like to behave differently based on the factor but I guess that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Something like this? https://play.golang.org/p/DKn_4KitBHb

Comment: Or rather this (a bit more refined) https://play.golang.org/p/mqDGjW21zMd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface should work here.

creating an interface like

```
type Stateful interface  {
    State() string
}
```

and a base state type

```
type BaseState struct{
}
func (s BaseState) State() string{
    return "Base state"
}
```

you can imbed the `BaseState` struct

```
type MyStruct struct{
    BaseState
}
```

so that `State` Will return `"Base state"`, but can also implement its own method.

```
func (s MyStruct) State() string{
    return "New State"
}
```

and now `State` will return `"New State"`

https://play.golang.org/p/QOajW0O6gIz

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `prettyName` as method on the `struct`, you can also define a member value of function type.

```
type State struct {
    prettyName func() string
}
```

Then you can set its value to any function at runtime

```
a := State{}
a.prettyName = func() string {
    return "I am a state!"
}
fmt.Println(a.prettyName())
a.prettyName = func() string {
    return "another state"
}
fmt.Println(a.prettyName())
```

This example is on [playground](https://play.golang.com/p/rLiKOpc3vRc)

Now you can define an interface type with `PrettyName` API and further algorithms/business logic will call `PrettyName`.

```
type StateAPI interface {
    PrettyName () string
}
```

To fit your `State` type into the `StateAPI` interface, you need to define a trivial `PrettyName` method around the private function member

```
func (s *State) PrettyName() string {
    return s.prettyName()
}
```

This is basically your original idea and it is totally legitimate. There is an example in the [go programming language book by Alan A. A. Donovan and Brian W. Kernighan](https://www.gopl.io/) with exactly this construct.
That example sorts music record by different fields, e.g., by year, by artist, etc. In order to use the [sort.Sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) API,

```
func Sort(data Interface)
```

The input data needs to have three methods

```
type Interface interface {
        // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
        Len() int
        // Less reports whether the element with
        // index i should sort before the element with index j.
        Less(i, j int) bool
        // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
        Swap(i, j int)
}
```

One way to sort by different fields is to define one custom data type for each case, say `ByYear`, `ByArtist`, etc. And define all three API methods for each case. But `Len` and `Swap` methods are redundant for all cases. A better solution is to define only one custom data type with a function member,

```
//!+customcode
type customSort struct {
    t    []*Track
    less func(x, y *Track) bool
}
func (x customSort) Less(i, j int) bool { 
     return x.less(x.t[i], x.t[j]) }
func (x customSort) Len() int           {
     return len(x.t) }
func (x customSort) Swap(i, j int)      {
     x.t[i], x.t[j] = x.t[j], x.t[i] }
```

Then you can programmically control what `less` means.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch7/sorting/main.go)